# Select query time out after SqlBulkCopy with transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, timeout, sqlbulkcopy

I have to do following operation on three tables one after another.

1. First insert data into table1
2. Bulk Copy into table2 (from data table for table2)
3. Select from table2 (and update data table for table 3)
4. Bulk Copy into table 3.

For all these, I am passing in same connection and transaction.

But after the 2nd step, when I execute the 3rd step...it is timing out.

Is it because, my bulk copy at step2 expect a commit/rollback? If so how do I handle it ?

**EDIT**

**WorkUnit** is a user defined class which has transaction and connection instances inside it...and have functions to commit and rollback the transaction.

**First step method**

```
public override int ExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand cmd, WorkUnit wu)
{
    int result;
    cmd.Connection = wu.WorkConnection;
    cmd.Transaction = wu.WorkTransaction;
    result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    return result;
}
```

**Second step method**

```
public override int BcpCall(string table, DataTable sourceTable, WorkUnit workUnit)
{
    int rowsCopied = 0;
    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy((SqlConnection)workUnit.WorkConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers, (SqlTransaction)workUnit.WorkTransaction))
    {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = table;
        bulkCopy.NotifyAfter = 10000;

        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(sourceTable);
        rowsCopied = GetRowsCopied(bulkCopy);
    }
    return rowsCopied;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How long does the whole operation take? Do you use `TransactionScope` or `SqlTransaction`? Please post some code.

Comment: We use sql transaction. Even if I try witha  snigle recod, it time out at third step.